# Find the first word and last few words in a string using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

Using these two regex expressions `regPrefix` and `regSuffix`,

```
final String POEM = "1. Twas brillig, and the slithy toves\n" + 
                    "2. Did gyre and gimble in the wabe.\n" +
                    "3. All mimsy were the borogoves,\n" + 
                    "4. And the mome raths outgrabe.\n\n";

String regPrefix = "(?m)^(\\S+)";   // for the first word in each line.
String regSuffix = "(?m)\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+$";  // for the last 3 words in each line.
Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile(regPrefix).matcher(POEM);
Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile(regSuffix).matcher(POEM);

while (m1.find() && m2.find()) {
    System.out.println(m1.group() + " " + m2.group());
}
```

I am getting the correct output as:

```
1. the slithy toves
2. in the wabe.
3. were the borogoves,
4. mome raths outgrabe.
```

Is it possible to *merge those two regex expressions* into one, and get the same output? I tried something like:

```
String singleRegex = "(?m)^(\\S+)\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+$";
```

but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to `split` and index?

Comment: May be, but this is for the purpose of learning complex regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a single pattern with two capture groups:

```
String regex = "(?m)^(\\S+).*?((?:\\s+\\S+){3})$";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(POEM);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + m.group(2));
}

1. the slithy toves
2. in the wabe.
3. were the borogoves,
4. mome raths outgrabe.
```

### Demo

Comment: Might consider `((?:\\s+\\S+){3})`, to repeat yourself less, and removing the need to concatenate a space in the `println` (assuming there aren't double-spaces at that point in the input there)

Comment: I don't know Java but I guess you can also do something like `m.replaceAll("$1 $2")`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance How on earth did you move to the top of the site in a few months?  Well, I'm not surprised, given your good advice here.

Comment: @SauravSahu It's called a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/4934172).